# Strings and Arrays

Tags: vb.net

I have this homework on visual basic, I understand what the code is suppose to do but I have no Idea how to do it

anyway this was the incomplete code

```
Function GetNextItem(NextLine As String) As String(,)
    Dim answer(0, 1) As String
    Dim String1, String2 As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0 'variable to store what character you are currently  looking at
    String1 = ""
    String2 = ""
    'Loop through the string until you hit a comma. Everything before the comma gets added   
one character at a time to String1


    'Add one more to i so it moves passed the comma

    'Loop from that character to the end of the string. Anything left gets added to String2

    'First block of the 1x2 array gets String1
    'Second block of the 1x2 array gest String2

    'The 1x2 array is returned
    Return answer
End Function
```

the instructions are in comments
I done a bit of it. I don't need the answers I just want to find a way to manoeuvre through this.
I really need help with this :3

Comment: Is this VBA or VB?  Different animals, you say VB but have VBA tag.

Comment: Glad you don't want us do your homework for you. We will be happy to help with your code when you get stuck. Look up for...next loops. That's a starting point. ;-)

Comment: You are asked to cut the string NextLine in half compared to the first encountered comma. string1 contains preceding the comma, string2  everything else after comma. The two strings are returned in an array of 2

Comment: Use Split(input,",") then loop through chars in that array.  Depending on VBA or VB, you'll need to redim the array to the longest return 1st or 2nd half to accommodate, so NAT,BBBB is 4 max length, and BBBB,NAT is still the same, but needs to be dimensioned off the max of the lengths.  VBA has some restrictions I believe on the column you can redim.  Or if the homework is on loops, google "for next in vb"

Comment: @user5414798 i don't think he can use split, because this is homework, and teachers want them to do how teachers like... unfortunatly.

I'll post a solution for this right away

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
Function GetNextItem(NextLine As String) As String(,)
    Dim answer(0, 1) As String
    Dim String1 As String = "", String2 As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer = 0 'variable to store what character you are currently  looking at
    'Loop through the string until you hit a comma. Everything before the comma gets addedone character at a time to String1
    For Each character In NextLine
        i = NextLine.IndexOf(character)
        If character <> ","c Then
            String1 += character
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'Add one more to i so it moves passed the comma
    '?????? - I don't think this part is needed

    'Loop from that character to the end of the string. Anything left gets added to String2
    Dim counter As Integer = -1
    For Each character In NextLine
        ' Can not use NextLine(character) here, because a string can have more than once the same character
        counter += 1
        If counter <= i Then Continue For
        String2 += character
    Next

    'First block of the 1x2 array gets String1
    answer(0, 0) = String1.Trim

    'Second block of the 1x2 array gest String2
    answer(0, 1) = String2.Trim

    'The 1x2 array is returned
    Return answer
End Function
```

Comment: Can he use ToCharArray? and an if to switch sides of the array on reaching comma? :o)

Comment: I don't know, he could of tell us if he is open to other methods or no, I'm saying this because once my teacher denied my exam because i used functions that she didn't teach me.... that's why

Comment: wasn't being awkward, just having a laugh :)

Comment: Well, we use visual studio in school, i'm not sure the difference between VB and VBA

Comment: Well, if you could use split would make the job way easier.
[Differences in VB .net and VBA](http://checktechno.blogspot.pt/2013/04/difference-between-vbnet-and-vba.html)
I will update the code to use split if you want.